# R[[X]] flat as a R[X]-module?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, modules, power-series, flatness

I assume $R[X]\rightarrow R[[X]]$ is not flat in general, but I was wondering if any conditions on a commutative ring $R$ are known such that $R[[X]]$ is flat as a $R[X]$-module.

Would $R$ noetherian be enough?

Comment: Yes, R noetherian in enough. See Atiyah-MacDonald, Proposition 10.14.

Comment: Many thanks! I'll keep poking around to see if I find a more general characterisation of $R$, but Noetherian works fine for what I need it for. Thanks again!

Comment: This in fact holds for any ring. First of all it holds when $R$ is an integral domain, since then the homomorphism $R[X] \to R[[X]]$ is universally torsion-free. (A module over an integral domain is flat iff it is universally torsion-free; this amounts to the fact that a torsion-free module over a valuation ring is flat.) Since the localization of a ring at a prime ideal is an integral domain, we may reduce to that case.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov:  The localization at a prime is a domain?!? Anyway, every $R$ is a quotient of a domain, so it certainly suffices to treat the case when $R$ is a domain, but in such cases why is the map "universally torsion-free" (whatever that means)? Formation of $R[\![X]\!]$ doesn't commute with scalar extension on $R$, etc.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov: The localization of a ring at a prime need not be a domain.  The ring $R=k[t,y_1,y_2,\dots]/(ty_1,ty_2,\dots)$ is such that $R[[x]]$ is not flat over $R[x]$ (consider the ideal generated by $t$ and an element like $\sum y_n x^n\otimes t$).

Comment: @user52824: Why does it suffice to consider the case when $R$ is a domain?  It is not true that $R/I[[x]]=R[[x]]\otimes_{R[x]} R/I[x]$ if $I$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: @user52824 (and @EricWofsely):  Oh yes, thank you; I apologize. A module $M$ over a domain $R$ is said to be *universally torsion-free* if for any homomorphism $R \to S$ to another domain, $M \otimes_R S$ is a torsion-free $S$-module. It seemed to me that this was evident in our case (first of all, clearly $R[[X]]$ is a domain, hence a torsion-free $R[X]$-module), but I was hasty about this. (I only had in mind morphisms $R[X] \to S[X]$ coming from an $R \to S$.) Again, I apologize.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Oops, sorry about the mistake. I agree, the natural inclusion $I \cdot R[\![X]\!] \subset I[\![X]\!]$ is generally not an equality when $I$ is not finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Comment: If $R[[X]]$ is flat over $R[X]$ then it is flat over $R$. So $R^\mathbb{N}$ must be a flat $R$-module; in other words, $R$ is a coherent ring.